# PoEEA logic of DataMapper / Domain Driven Design

Tags: design-patterns, datamapper

I am a little confused about the logic of the DataMapper pattern.

What I have so far (pseudo code, not looking for language specific answers here):

```
class Car implements DomainObjectAbstract {
    ... properties ...
    ... accessors / mutators ...
    ... behaviors ... // drive, park, whatever.
}

class House implements DomainObjectAbstract {
    ... properties ...
    ... accessors / mutators ...
    // may not have behaviors, a house doesn't 'do anything, it just is'
}

class DaoCar implements DaoAbstract {
    // some code to handle reading and writing car object to database table
}

class DaoHouse implements DaoAbstract {
    // some code to handle reading and/or writing house object to an xml file
}

class DataMapper {
    protected _dao;
    protected _model;

    function getDao() return this->_dao;
    function setDao( DomainObjectAbstract dao) this->_dao = dao;
    function getModel() return this->_model;
    function setModel( DaoAbstract model ) this->_model = model;

    function create() { // create a new instance of the model }
    function save() { // create or update the model into persistent storage }
    function fetch( id ) { // fetch record from storage and return a property populated model }
    ... etc ...
}
```

Question: What would the purpose of multiple DataMappers be?

What I mean is, why would I have a HouseDataMapper and a CarDataMapper, considering the DataMapper should not care about either the model or the dao, except that it follows the implemention rules.  My only thought would be different DataMappers for different abstract (rules) for different models and data access objects.  I ask because most of the examples I see talk about a HouseDataMapper and CarDataMapper as being separate entities, would that not break the DataMapper PoEEA's purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further reading, I see my mistake:

"The Data Mapper is a layer of software that separates the in-memory objects from the database. Its responsibility is to transfer data between the two and also to isolate them from each other." - [Martin Fowler, P of EAA (Data Mapper)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)

So where my confusion was, the Data Mapper (concrete) should know about the in-memory objects (instantiated model objects), it just isolates them from the database (data access object).